# Angularjs injected controller empty when testing with Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I am currently working with **Angular and using Karma and Jasmine** to make the testing. The filters, for example are injected to the main module and can be tested without any problem, but when I try to test the controllers I get an **empty object** after the injection.

Here is the code of my main module:

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    var dependencies = [];

    angular.module('myApp', dependencies)

}());
```

The controller that I am to test:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myApp')

        .controller('NavCtrl', ['$scope',
            function ($scope) {

                $scope.currentUser = null;

            }]);
}());
```

And finally the test suite:

```
describe ("controller", function() {

    beforeEach(module("myApp"));

    var $scope, $rootScope, controllerLoader;

    beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
        $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();

        var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');

        controllerLoader = function() {
            return $controller('NavCtrl', {
                '$scope': $scope
            });
        };
    }));

    it ("testing injection", function() {

        var controller = controllerLoader();
        expect(controller).toNotEqual({});

    })

});
```

But the result of the test is **FAIL**, and after debugging I see that the injected controller is empty. I have already tried to give a false name for the controller and the test just crashes, what means that the controller is detected but for any reason I am not getting its properties.

Comment: Try to move `var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');` inside the `controllerLoader` function.

Comment: why do you want to access controller? in test case you already have the access to `$scope`

Comment: That worked, I didn't know how to properly access to the controller. Obviously, thinking twice, I have to do it through the `$scope`. Thank you a lot!

Comment: how did you solve this? i'm new to karma/jasmine/angularjs...running into this problem as well but don't understand why...

Comment: check the comment of @doodeec

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue. The difference is that in my application I am using RequireJS, so some parts are a little different, but I guess the overall might help you.

I modified it to match your names:

```
define(['app/app.module', 'angular', 'angular-mocks'], function () {

  describe('Controller Unit test', function () {

    var $controller;

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_) {
        // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
        $controller = _$controller_;
    }));

    describe('Get the controller', function () {
        it('should contain controller', function () {
            var $scope = {};
            var controller = $controller('NavCtrl', {$scope: $scope});

            console.log(controller);
            expect(controller).toBeDefined();
        });
    });
  });
});
```

It is very important to load both angular and angular-mocks. **However I think the main issue is that your `controllerLoader` function is in `beforeEach` section. The injection has to be made in the `describe` section of the test itself.**