# AngularJS Controller empty after Jasmine injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I want to test an AngularJS controller with Jasmine. My problem is:
After creating the controller, the object is empty.

Here is the AngularJS controller:

```
    angular
      .module('controlcenter.reports')
      .controller('ReportsController', ReportsController);

    ReportsController.$inject = ['$scope', '$state', 'Api'];

    function ReportsController($scope, $state, Api) {

      var getReportWebsites = function() {
        Api.getReportsWebsites().then(function(reports) {
          $scope.reports = reports.data;
        }, function(error) {
          console.log('error', error);
        });
      };

       $scope.showDetails = function(id) {
        $state.go('reportDetails.overview', {id: id});
      };

      getReportWebsites();
    }
```

And here is my test:

```
describe('ReportsController', function() {

  var scope;
  var ctrl;

  beforeEach(module('controlcenter.reports'));
  beforeEach(module('authentication'));
  beforeEach(module('api'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    ctrl = $controller('ReportsController', {$scope: scope});
  }));

  it('dummy test', function(){
    spyOn('ctrl', getReportWebsites);
  });
});
```

[I've read this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22632748/angularjs-injected-controller-empty-when-testing-with-jasmine), so I put the functions inside the scope. But even this is empty.

I've read tons of Controller testing tutorials, but even after just copy&pasting the code, my controller is always empty.

> So, how to properly test an AngularJS controller?

I also don't want to put everything inside the scope, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `spyOn('ctrl', getReportWebsites);` uses an undefined symbol: `getReportWebsites`. And the 1st argument should be an object, not a string, so what you probably mean is: `spyOn(ctrl, 'getReportWebsites');`

But now your controller does not have `getReportWebsites` as a method. It is private in the controller's constructor closure.

What you really want is:

- Either place `getReportWebsites` in the controller object, so instead of `var getReportWebsites = function(...)` do `this.getReportWebsites = function(...)` and use the spy as I have written above.
- Or mock the `Api`/spy on the `Api.getReportsWebsites` method.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But a question: How to test private methodes then? I thought I inject the controller, so I have access to it (also the private methodes).

Comment: Are you sure private methods are to be tested? (hint: NO) Private methods are part of the implementation, not the contract of an artifact (the controller here). Testing them would tie the test to the specific implementation, making the test brittle. On the other hand, if you find yourself needing to test a private method, consider whether it should be part of the contract, e.g. made public